# Color QR Code Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I created this custom QR Code.  Can you figure out how to decode the entire message and explain the symbolism behind the color choices?

[image: Custom QR Code]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pretty simple.

> These are actually two QR codes. The dark part is the common part. The blue one says "Donald John Trump". The red one - "Hillary Rodham Clinton". The colors are the colors of the parties, but I don't know why they are switched.

Update: based on @squeamishossifrage comment, the colors just represent the anaglyph glasses colors.

> Edit again: When you look through these glasses, you see the opposite color through every lens, i.e. you see Trump through the red lens and Hillary through the blue one, so that's how the colors correspond to the party colors.

Comment: Here, [try these on](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Anaglyph_glasses.png)

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage This was my first guess, before I decoded it. I'm not American and didn't expect to see Trump _here_.

Comment: ...but if you find him anywhere, he's going to be to the right of Clinton, which is why I thought the goggles might help :-)